# Show first 10 custom post type posts that meet ACF value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I've got a custom post-type set up called 'Services' and within that is an Advanced Custom Field called 'completed' which is radio button returning either 'inc' or 'com'

The issue I've got is that when the below code runs it grabs the first 10 posts regardless of whether or not they meet the meta query I've got below

Essentially what I'm looking for is the first 10 posts that are 'inc' to display on the page

```
$tArgs = array(
    'post_type'       => 'services',
    'posts_per_page'  => 10,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'completed',
            'value' => 'inc',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    ),            
);
```

I would expect this to loop over the 'Services' post type and only return the first 10 posts that have the value 'Inc' for the completed ACF

Comment: What is the exact setup of your ACF radio button? Does it _really_ store `inc` or `com` in the database - or maybe just an index?

Comment: @CBroe - https://imgur.com/nsXtz3d

Comment: From what I can see the posts are completing the check, but if for example:

In the first 10 posts, two of them are 'com', then on the frontend I will only see 8 posts where I need it to continue checking until it's found 10 'inc' posts

Comment: `posts_per_page` should apply to the result including all the conditions. Plus, the meta query looks correct - so I would expect this to not give you any posts at all if there is no value match, rather than all of them. (Just to be absolutely sure - the query result you are looking at is really based on those $tArgs parameters, yes? You are not perhaps looking at the result of the "normal" main query WP performs by itself?)

Comment: @CBroe - https://snipit.io/public/snippets/77183

here's the setup with a few bits redacted but this should hopefully give you the code to read over and make sense of

Comment: Hm, sorry, can't spot anything wrong with that. What happens when you make the meta condition into something what could never be fulfilled - like, make up a key name, and change the operator to `=`, so that it should definitively not be able to find _any_ matching posts - do you get nothing as you should then, or are there still posts coming?

Comment: When I do that no posts are coming through at all which is what I find confusing

Comment: Okay, that at least tells us that the meta query itself must be working. You are using the `LIKE` comparison operator there - what happens when you use that with `'value' => '%inc%'`, any change?